# AWS S3 Bucket created with force_delete=true fails to delete with Access Denied via terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I create an s3 bucket via terraform for the purpose of storing VPC Flow Logs:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket                      = local.bucket_name
  force_destroy               = true
  tags                        = var.tags
}
```

After the bucket is created, and flow-log service is created, there are a few entries under "/AWSLogs/..."

after I remove the flow-log service I attempt the terraform destroy, but it fails with the following entry, one for each object:

```
deleting: S3 object (AWSLogs/.../...98d659c.log.gz) version (null): AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

there are no policies, because they get deleted first.

ACLs are `bucket owner` and `s3 log delivery group` have full access, the rest are turned off. and owner is set to `data.aws_canonical_user_id.current.id`

Answer (score 0):

ACL permissions are not quite enough. The IAM role you are using requires the `s3:DeleteObject*` permissions.